# Android minimum sdk - Android Studio Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android and having some trouble with Android Studio.
I'm trying to set my `minimumSDK` version to 11 and have it set in `AndroidManifest.xml`,but keep getting errors saying it's still set to 8.

Comment: Clean your project and if possible restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You set the minimum SDK in the `build.gradle` file in Android Studio. Be careful there are two similarly named files in your project. It should be the one located inside your module, not your root project folder.

Answer (score -1):

1. Change your Android manifest.xml to:

   `<uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="11"
      android:targetSdkVersion="xx" />
    <application 
      ...
     />`
2. Clean the project
3. Restart the eclipse (If required)

Note: There will be 2 AndroidManifest.xml

```
1. Project/Bin/AndroidManifest.xml
2. Project/AndroidManifest.xml   --> This is the one that has to be changed.
```

However, ensure that it is correct in both the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The asker was asking about Android Studio, not Eclipse.